# Maya standalone play-blast not shown in display layer

Tags: python, maya

I have some display layer, but in **standalone mode**, the layer is not shown in the video.the maya version is **2018.5**

```py
import maya.standalone
maya.standalone.initialize(name='python')

cmds.file(r"E:\tmp\ani.ma", open=True)

cmds.playblast(format='qt',

filename='D:/programeCode/t2.mov',
               forceOverwrite=1,
               sequenceTime=0, clearCache=1,
               viewer=1, showOrnaments=1, offScreen=True, fp=4, 
               percent=100,
               compression='H.264', quality=100, widthHeight=(1920, 818))
```

I tried to set the layer `hideOnPlayback`, but it also didn't work.

Comment: playblast doesnt work in batch. so it might be your problem ^^'